# Jasmine test for javascript

Tags: jasmine

I am learning jasmine framework to write unit tests for javascript. In an attempt to do this, I have tried writing a unit test for my javascript function.  But it didn’t succeed.

my Javascipt function is as below :

```
    Toggle.test=function(){
        trackClick ():
    }     



    var toggleButton =$(‘#toggleButton’);
                toggleButton.click(trackClick);

                 function trackClick() {
                   if (toggleButton.hasClass('open')){
   trackingObject.getReady(function(){
trackingObject.trackt('o',‘eventId’,{
             var1: “exp.kpy”,
              var2: “exp.kcy"
       });
    });
     }

     else{
        trackingObject.getReady(function(){
        trackingObject.track('o','eventId',{
                 var1: “clp.kcy”,
                 var2: "clp.kcy"
        });
     });
     }
     }
```

To test the above function I have wriiten a jasmine unit test as follows:

```
    describe(“TestTracking“,function(){
          var toggleButton,
                 trackingObject;

    beforeEach(function(){
         toggleButton = $('#toggleButton');         

    window.trackingObject = {
             getReady: function(arg){
              },                     
              track: function(args){ 
              }
    }

    trackingObject=window.trackingObject

    spyOn(trackingObject,“getReady”).and.callThrough();
    spyOn(trackingObject,“track”).and.callThrough()
    });

     describe(‘Toggle’, function () {         
    it("Toggle expand", function () {
       var open = 'open';

    spyOn(toggleButton,'hasClass').and.callFake(function(open) {
         return true;
     });

    Toggle.test();

expect(trackingObject.trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('o', ‘eventId’, {
var1: “exp.kpy”,
           vr2: “exp.kcy”
     });                                                                               
     });
     });
```

The issue that I am facing is when the control reaches if (toggleButton.hasClass('open')) { in  trackClick() function it evaluates to false and doesn’t enter the if block even when I have spied on it as:

```
    spyOn(toggleButton,'hasClass').and.callFake(function(open) {
        return true;
 });
```

could anyone please help solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please fix your formatting?

Comment: As I am posting through mobile, formatting is a bit difficult.